# C# .NET MAUI - How to read an image and convert it to an array of Color?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I've found a lot of ways to get pixel colors using the `Bitmap` class, but only on Windows platforms. For other platforms, I only know that I can get `Byte` arrays, but not the `Color` of each pixel.

Do I need to write platform-specific code to do this? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your goal and what have you tried already?

Comment: Use SkiaSharp to get individual pixel values.  See the linked question

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) is a platform independent solution (disclaimer: written by me) that can be used the same way for `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and `SkiaSharp.SKBitmap`. You can find also some MAUI applications among the [examples](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/tree/master/Examples).